# TV viewership data

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset of TV viewership or ratings over different networks/shows. Specifically I need this for NBC's broadcasting of the Olympics. I've found various articles discussing numbers for different days, but not a single dataset covering all days. Online streaming numbers would also be useful, but not expecting any structured dataset around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a dataset containing viewership and rating numbers by day for the first week of Olympic games in Rio this year. It also contains data from London 2012 for comparison. https://www.datazar.com/file/fcf5766ab-2c8a-4ced-8b4b-a7381d9cab09

I feel that it will be much easier to find more ratings like this, if not more extensive ones, in a few weeks or so.

*Full disclosure: I work at Datazar (A collaborative data library where), where this file is being hosted.*

Comment: Thanks for providing that data. It's a good start, but I'm also interested in the other days, including the opening ceremony (Aug 5). Everything I've seen so far has been a summarizing article. I was hoping there exists some raw data feed, maybe something Nielsen would provide.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at what sites are being downloaded off torrent sites and news groups with Python http://www.tvoverlord.com/ library